# c++ force choice or ignoring dialog box (message box) with promt programatically CertAddCertificateContextToStore

Tags: c++, windows, dialog, certificate, box

I’m trying to add certificate to the Trust Root Storage using CertAddCertificateContextToStore () But execution of my program stops at the message box(dialog box) with windows warning and questions : …. Do you want to install this certificate? Yes No
Could someone suggest some idea how I may force promt with choosing “Yes” programmatically?  Or maybe how adding certificate ignoring this message and continue the execution of my program?
I have not found any information about that yet.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Adding a certificate to the trusted root storage seriously impacts security of the OS. This is the reason why this function shows this message. It is designed to force users explicitly confirm this action, otherwise malware would be able to install it's certificates as trusted root. There is no correct way to ignore this message and your software should not try to avoid it.